# jquery slider auto start function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Friends I have a image slider on my site

slides images by click on preview and next button.

My question is: is it possible to add auto start instead of onclik ?

Here is my codes:

> $(document).ready(function(){
>         var currentPosition = 0;
>         var slideWidth = 560;
>         var slides = $('.slide');
>         var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
>
> ```
>   // Remove scrollbar in JS
>   $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');
>
>   // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
>   slides
>     .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
>     // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
>   .css({
>       'float' : 'left',
>       'width' : slideWidth
>     });
>
>   // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
>   $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
>
>   // Insert controls in the DOM
>   $('#slideshow')
>     .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
>     .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');
>
>   // Hide left arrow control on first load
>   manageControls(currentPosition);
>
>   // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
>   $('.control')
>     .bind('click', function(){
>     // Determine new position
>   currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
>
>   // Hide / show controls
>     manageControls(currentPosition);
>     // Move slideInner using margin-left
>     $('#slideInner').animate({
>       'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
>     });
>   });
>
>   // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
>   function manageControls(position){
>     // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
>   if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
>   // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
>     if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
>   }   
> });
> </script>
> ```

Comment: a quick solution could be to trigger a `click` event on fixed intervals using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` e.g. append at the end of your code something like `setInterval(function(){$('.control').trigger('click');},2000);` this will auto slide every 2secs

Comment: thanks for the answer when I do that under the codes it starts automoticly but shows only 1 image goes to left and back to right. here is the function  `$('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
 currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
    
 // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);`

Comment: that would be because your currentPosition assignment depends on the calling element, and so breaks when being called from the timing event, it will always equate to currentPosition-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could separate out the functionality in the click to a different function, then call it at an interval. **[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acarlon/gRNBE/1/)** shows a simple example.

```
var rotation = 90;
function doAnim()
{
    var rotationString = 'rotateY(' + rotation + 'deg)'
    $('#slideOne').css('webkit-transform',rotationString);
    $('#slideTwo').css('webkit-transform',rotationString);
    $('#slideOne').css('transform',rotationString);
    $('#slideTwo').css('transform',rotationString);    
    rotation += 90;
}

$(function(){    
    setInterval(doAnim,1000);
});
```

If you are using jquery 1.7+, then you might want to consider changing the `bind` event to `on`. See `on` documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: thanks for answers its hard for me I am terrible in javascript and jquery cant fix it :( 
I am going to change slider to another one with ready function.

thanks again to all of you..

Comment: @SerapUygur - glad to help. I just realised that I forgot to put the link to the demo. I have updated my answer, or you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/acarlon/gRNBE/1/

Answer (score 0):

As melc mentioned. You can simply use a timer to achieve either an autostart, or a slideshow effect. The following code is a good starting point for you, however you would probably want to update it a fair bit to add stop/start functionality, return to start...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //auto start after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.control').click();
    },3000);

    //slideshow - every 3 seconds
    var slider = setInterval(function(){
        $('.control').click();
    },3000);

});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you may also want to have a look at scrolling content demo I have created - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/mHyBv

Comment: thanks for answers its hard for me I am terrible in javascript and jquery cant fix it :( 
I am going to change slider to another one with ready function.

thanks again to all of you..